# 3d vector postions

Tags: geometry, vectors

Cartesian coordinates...

Given a starting position of $x_1=0, y_1=0, z_1=0$ travelling to a destination position of $x_2=500,y_2=500, z_2=500$.

I can calculate the length of the connecting vector(I know how to do this)

I want to calculate the coordinates of the position $x_3, y_3, z_3$ after travelling distance (d) down the vector from position 1 to position 2

I  have standard o-level maths, I can apply a formula in programming, but this level of geometry is beyond my grasp.

Comment: your second question is not very clear to me. Can you please elaborate? "I want to calculate the coordinates of the position d (distance) along the vector giving $x_3,y_3,z_3$."

Comment: I have edited, hopefully more clear now, my bad - sorry

Comment: @RocketAndy Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given is the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traveling vector is given by the parametric equation

$$OP=(x_0,y_0,z_0)+t(x_2,y_2,z_2)=t(500,500,500)$$

with $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: I dont understand the answer, I have a vector, which I want to travel a distance down say 100 units, I want to calculate my new position on that vector.  My maths is quite basic.

Comment: @RocketAndy Sorry I didn't get fully the meaning of your question, if you move down (along z) say of 100 from position 2 you finish at $(x_3,y_3,x_3)=(500,500,500-100)=(500,500,400)$. Is it clear now?

Comment: Sort of but I want to travel 100 units down the vector not along an axis, when I arrive how do I calculate my xyz.   I apologise again for the lack of clarity

Comment: @RocketAndy Sorry I lost this last comment. To determine a position you have to fix a starting point and a direction. What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question:

The length of the *connecting vector* is given by 
$$l = \Vert (x_1, y_1, z_1) - (x_2, y_2, z_2) \Vert_{2} = \sqrt{(x_{1} - x_{2})^{2} + (y_{1} - y_{2})^{2} + (z_{1} - z_{2})^{2}} = \sqrt{3 \times 500^{2}} = 866.025403784$$

Comment: Yes hence “I can calculate”, it was a statement sorry I wasn’t clear.